# Can't boot in Ubuntu after windows upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, boot-failure

After my lastest update for Ubuntu and Windows XP, I got a Grub error on booting the next day. `ls` lists the following (without () ):

```
sd0 sd1, msdos sd2 sd5 sd6
```

When I tried to get into one with `(sd0,xy)/` it doesn't detect system or unknown file system error.

I tried to boot to a live session with a Knoppix live CD and found out that all data exists. I also tried to recover with  TestDisk and it finds all systems. Here is the test disk result:

```
                          Start        End     Size in sectors
 1 * HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1  7079 254 63  113740137
 2 E extended LBA          7080   0  1 12161 254 63   81642330
 5 L HPFS - NTFS           7080   1  1 10266 254 63   51199092 [Schule]
   X extended             12031  30  1 12161 254 63    2102625
 6 L Linux Swap           12031  31 33 12161 254 63    2102530
```

I've 1 winxp-home, 1x Ubuntu (ext3+swap) and 1 winxp prof and then I wrote on mbr with TestDisk but I always get the same errors with Grub.

What should I do? I need both XP and Ubuntu. Help me please.

more infos in answers below - sry for thos confusing style but im working on diff live system and browsers and have to reboot always

the boot info script output is also down below

maybe an advanced user can correct my fail posting - after i can solve my issuse i will register here

thanx and pls help me with those weired issues !

---

as i still cant just comment my own answer or those on top i again has to put it here as a sepperate answer..... (or even edit - maybe an browser failur using the live cds ... cause this posti can edit)

here the bootinfo script output - but the result is the same as with TestDisk ... but it looks worse - cause it also doesnt detect my old ubuntu ... but there wasnt a eares process or overwrite process visibile ending the last working session

output:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]
```

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sda1: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows XP
Boot files:        /boot.ini /ntldr /NTDETECT.COM
```

sda2: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                   at sector 63.
Operating System:  Windows XP
Boot files:
```

sda6: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Disk /dev/sda: 100.0 GB, 100030242816 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12161 cylinders, total 195371568 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *             63   113,740,199   113,740,137   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2         113,740,200   195,382,529    81,642,330   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5         113,740,263   164,939,354    51,199,092   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda6         193,280,000   195,382,529     2,102,530  82 Linux swap / Solaris

/dev/sda2 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda
/dev/sda6 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda

"blkid" output: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs
/dev/sda1        6596D86768011128                       ntfs
/dev/sda5        1300D3B7744EC141                       ntfs       Schule
/dev/sda6        5b95f2a1-4145-43a5-ac51-41d7dd32b213   swap

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)

================================ sda1/boot.ini: ================================

---

[boot loader]

timeout=30

default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS

[operating systems]

multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition" /fastdetect /NoExecute=OptOut

multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect

[spybotsd]

timeout.old=30

---

the last part shows that i now use the windows boot loader so that i can acces at least one OS 
but shouldnt i also get acces to my ubuntu partitions with live-linux-cds ?
or do i have to boot with grub to get to those files only ??

Comment: ugh how do i login to this question - or better register so that i can respond on your answers better ?????
i dont wonat to spam my own thread full - and it would be more readable :( ugh well how do u mean - ive 12.04 and a 11. somewhat cd - so i should enter with ubuntu instead of knoppix ? cause under knoppix i should also be able to run grub update ? hm but the problem is i can acces to the ntfs-winxp partitions but cant mount the linux ext3 partitions - i get an error when i use the mnt command but i´ve to say that im a beginner and not quite sure if i used that right

Comment: as i mentioned before i cant mount my linux partition and not even see if the data is available neiter with knoppix or ubuntu live cd that is sad - i installed now boot-rescue and made this link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1370074/   and i also dont get any information about my older ubuntu install - or ist that normal     and which sda should i select ? those with win-xp on it ?

Comment: bith boot-repair i got win-xp running at least.... but when you klick on the link - why i dont cant find data on my ubuntu drive ???    this is sad :( - what could i do else to get my linux data ?   normally wiht an live cd i should be able to get into those drive or not ?

Comment: hm sry i couldnt - as my problem is a bootloader problem im trying different things and have to reboot (and not into the acutall session of the first post) - and didnt regerst so far cause i need a solution quick :(    - but now as i see it cant get solved quick i should have registerted - and as i replied as VanceAnce user i couldnt add a comment on my own first post :( :( or even edit it - else i would have done it for a better readable post :( - sry for that

Comment: you should register your account - this will allow you to edit your question even when the browser cookie is lost.

Answer (score 2):

When you install or update Windows, Windows assumes it's the only OS on the machine—or at least it doesn't account for Linux. So, it replaces GRUB with its own boot loader.

What you have to do is to replace the Windows boot loader with GRUB. Simply chroot into your install and run update-grub.

[Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432) how you go about it :)

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is only with GRUB and it shows GRUB error then insert Ubuntu disk and enter into "Try Ubuntu" then open your terminal and type `sudo update-grub` (or) if it didn't work then re-install Ubuntu in existing one and the will automatically set.

This works only if your problem is only with GRUB.